# Error on populate Dropdownlist using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, drop-down-menu

Hy guys n gals I am trying to populate a sub-list on changing the main list. I use dropdownlist  for both.

Here is my jquery :

```
     $(document).ready(function() {

      $('.ddl1').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'myajax.asmx/getSubs',                
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',

            data: { txt: $('.ddl1').val() },
            success: function(data) {                  
                $('.ddl1sub').empty(); 
                for (row in data) {
                $('.ddl1sub').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', data[row].account_Id).text(data[row].account_Name));
               }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

here is the server function:

```
  [WebMethod]
    public List<Account_Dto> getSubs(String txt)
    {
    accounts_DAL ad = new accounts_DAL();  
    DataTable dt = ad.get_Sub_Acc(txt);

    List<Account_Dto> result = new List<Account_Dto>();
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        Account_Dto sub = new Account_Dto();
        sub.account_Name = row["sub_account_Name"].ToString();
        sub.account_Id = int.Parse(row["sub_account_Id"].ToString());
        result.Add(sub);
    }

    return result;
}
```

But I get an error   **'Sytax Error : Unexpected token <'**   on changing the main list. Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: The problem is because the JSON being returned is not formatted correctly. To determine exactly why that is I suggest you inspect the response using DevTools.

Comment: I'm somewhat agreeing, but need to see for myself. You can also check if you have the correct json format using a Chrome plugin named JSONView. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en

Comment: But How to use JSONView ? I installed it and executed the page again but nothing happens ..